# Recursive parsing of ongoing input

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm currently writing a PinYin Parser. To avoid missunderstandings: I mean a parser that recognizes valid PinYin sylables.

I have a working solution for parsing whole PinYin tokens. However I want to extend it to yield auto-completion upon typing and especially with correction this approach doesn't proof to be the right design.

I therefore generated a Parsetree in form of a json object with all valid sequences:

```
 { 'm':{'i':{'o'{'n',...}, 'u':{},...}, 'a': {...}, ...
   'p':{'i':{'u'},....
```

with this lookups of single charakters can be made. For example from the ON_KEY_DOWN event of an input field.

```
var LocalTree = GlobalParseTree;
function parse(inputChar){
     var NewLocalTree = LocalTree[inputChar];
     if (NewLocalTree === undefined){
         return -1; // invalid input
     }
     if (NewLocalTree === {}){
         return 0; // we have reached the end of the branch, parsing complete.
     }
     LocalTree = NewLocalTree;
     return 1; // a successfull parsing step has been made
}
```

Upon backspace-input I can now take the shorter value and reparse it again starting from the GlobalParseTree or I could store the LocalTrees in an array and .pop() it to restore the parser's Context. Both would work.

However, I would like to do it recursively and utilize the callingscope of each recursion as the parser's Context stack,
so that when a correction is made, only the last recursion needs to return and the rest of the parseTree doesn't need to be rebuild.

But I can't get my head arround how to make recursion work with ongoing input, since in the above code calling the function with input is what would trigger the next recursion (there is none yet).

Thanks for your answers. Even if the say, that input-triggered recursion is not possible.

Comment: Have you tried the [`onkeyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.onkeyup) event instead?

Comment: You mean catching the character `onkeydown` and do parsing `onkeyup`? Interesting idea, but the key problem I face is how to build recurison into (or arround) this parse function, so that the recursion does not occur from within, but eventdriven. Now that I think of it, I should put the return value into an outer global variable and pass an eventlistener into the function, so that every time an event is triggerd, it is available inside the function.

Comment: If `onkeyup` provides you with the most recent updated string (including the next character, or removing the last character), you don't need to know **which** key was pressed, you can just pop off the last character in the string to parse.